# Min/Max of $f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2-12x$ on $[-3,2]$

Tags: calculus

We want to find out the minima and maxima of the function

$$f:[-3,2] \to \mathbb{R} \text{ with } f(x) = 2x^3+3x^2-12x$$

I tried

$$f'(x)=6x^2+6x-12 =0 \\ x_1 = 1, x_2 = -2$$

Then we get

$$f(1) = -7 \\ f(-2) = 20 \\ f(-3) = 9 \\ f(2) = 4$$

But how does that lead us to finding out that the function has local maxima in $-2$ and $2$  and local minima in $1$ and $-3$?

[image]

Comment: Check $f''$. Moreover, to find the global min or max, you also have to check what are $f(-3)$ and $f(2)$.

Comment: How is $x_1=0$ a solution of $f'(x)$ ? Shouldn't it be  $x_1=1$ ?

Comment: @LaylaBailey Sorry that was a typo

Comment: you can check $f''$, if $f''(a)>0$, then $x=a$ is local minima, if $f''(a)<0$, it is local maxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $f'(x)=6x^2+6x-12$ vanishes at $x_1=1,x_2=-2$. We can differentiate again, to obtain $f''(x)=12x+6$. Since, $f''(1)=18 > 0$ it is a local minima and $f''(-2)=-18<0$ implies that it is a local maxima.

Note that the $f''(x)$ calculation only tells us about minima/maxima at the places where $f'(x)=0$. We will have to apply a different method for the boundary points.

We can note that in the vicinity of $x=-3, f'(x) > 0$. This tells us that the function *increases* from $x=-3$, i.e. for a little bit **after** $x=-3$, the function goes up **from** $f(-3)$, implying that it is a local minimum.

We can similarly note that near $x=2, f'(x)>0$. This tells us that for a little bit **before** $x=2$, the function increases, i.e. goes up **to** $f(2)$. This tells us that it is a local maximum.

Comment: And why do we look at the vicinity of $x= -3$ and $x = 2$ and not $x = -1$ for example?

Comment: We can also look at the vicinity of $x=-1$. Since $f'(-1)=-12$, the function decreases nearby it. However, since the function is defined for values both greater than and less than $-1$, the function goes down to $f(-1)$ and then continues decreasing. For a minima/maxima at $x=a, f(a+\delta) \text {and} f(a-\delta) $ both must be greater(for minima) or lesser (for maxima) than $f(a)$. ($\delta$ is some infinitely small positive value)

Comment: So we only have to take the boundaries into account and the values for which $f'(x) = 0$?

Comment: In general, yes. Any point nearby which $f'(x)$ suddenly changes from +ve to -ve or vice versa is also considered.

Comment: But if we take $f'(-3) = 24$ and $f'(2) = 24$, then both are $>0$, but why is $2$ a local maxima and not a local minima?

Comment: Consider that the function is defined for $x>-3$. Thus all values of $x$ nearby $-3$ for which $f$ is defined are more than $-3$. Since it is increasing here, $f(x)$ at all values nearby is more than $f(-3)$. Thus it is a minima.

For $x=2$ the situation is the opposite. All $x$ nearby on which $f$ is defined are less than $2$. Thus all $f(x)$ nearby are less than $f(2)$ which tells us that it is a maxima.

Comment: You meant to say that the function goes up from $f(\color{red}{-}3)$.

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution of $f'(x)=0$ are $x_1 = 1,x_2 = -2$. First calculate $f''(x)$, i.e. one more derivative of the function $f'(x)$. Then substitute the zeroes $x_1,x_2$ into it. Check whether

$f''(x_i) < 0$ => you will have a local maximum at $x_i$

$f''(x_i) > 0$ => you will have a local minimum at $x_i$

with $i$ being either i=1 or i=2 in this case.

Finally check the boundaries of the interval, $x=-3,x=2$. Here you can substitute the boundary x-values into $f'(x)$, the slope of the function at these points. For the lower bound of interval (here -3) you will have a local maximum if $f'(x)<0$ and local minimum if $f'(x)>0$, for the upper bound (here 2) you will have a local minimum if $f'(x)<0$ and local maximum if $f'(x)>0$

Comment: I don't understand. $f''(x) = 12x + 6$. Then according to that definition $f''(-3) = -30$ and it should be a local maximum because $f''(x) < 0$. But $-3$ is the local minimum

Comment: I have edited the explanation, check first derivatives on the boundaries.

Comment: So, step-for-step it goes like this? Step $1$: Calculate $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$. Step $2$: Calculate $f'(x) = 0$. Step $3$: Put the zeros values into $f''(x)$. Step $4:$ Calculate $f'(x)$ taking the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

As easy as it is to take the 2nd derivative, in this problem, I (still) would not do it.  This is regardless of whether it is the problem composer's intent that the 2nd derivative be taken.

The reason is that since there was more than one critical point, where the 1st derivative was $(0)$, the second derivative would automatically be *inconclusive*, with respect to the *boundary points*.

Here, taking advantage of the fact that the function is continuous throughout the interval, I would do the same thing that the original poster did.  That is, I would only take the 1st derivative, and then manually check the value of $f(x)$ at all critical points, as well as the boundary points.

Since the function is continuous (and differentiable throughout the interval), the above strategy guarantees that the minimum value of the function will be found.

---

An exception to the concept in this response is that if (for example) you had $(10)$ critical points in the pertinent interval, and if (for example) you were only looking for the minimum value of $f(x)$ in this interval, then I would strive to take the 2nd derivative.  This way, when manually checking specific points, as well as the boundary points, I could eliminate half of the critical points from consideration.